# How do I apply a thick border to one side of cell

Tags: excel, vba

I wanted to know how to apply say a thick right border to all selected cells on Excel, preferably using a shortcut. I tried recording a macro and then applying a thick border and erasing the top, bottom and left cells, but that just meant only the top cell had the right border, and the rest of the selection had left and right borders.

I only just discovered macros on excel so if there's a code I need to enter, if you wouldn't mind telling me what to do before and after I enter the code in order for it to work, that would be great.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this should work...

```
Dim MyRange as range
MyRange = activesheet.range("C1:C14")
MyRange.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
MyRange.Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThick 
MyRange.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
MyRange.Borders(xlInsideVertical).Weight = xlThick
```

Selection can be used in place of the MyRange Range object

```
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight).Weight = xlThick 
Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlContinuous
Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).Weight = xlThick
```

Other line weight constants...

```
    'other weight constants...
    'xlHairline 
    'xlMedium 
    'xlThick 
    'xlThin
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Sub ThickLeftBorders()
'Clear existing borders
Selection.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
'Apply left border
With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThick
End With
'Apply inside border (Left on all other columns in range)
With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .Weight = xlThick
End With
End Sub
```