# xlsx writer - How to get a thick border on only 1 side of a cell?

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I'm writing some pandas dataframes to an excel file. I was wondering if it's possible to write a format to have just a thick right border for example. I tried the below:

```
 center_thick_rborder = workbook.add_format({'align' : 'center',
                                             'right' : True,
                                             'border':5})
```

but it just applied a thick border to every border in the column, where I only want the right border. Is this possible? If so, how?

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49641690/thick-border-in-xlsxwriter) which is where I got the `'border':5` bit from in the above code. I've also seem [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28684330/how-do-i-apply-a-thick-border-to-one-side-of-cell) which didn't help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the border thickness for the `right` property, like this:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

center_thick_rborder = workbook.add_format({'align': 'center',
                                            'right': 5})

worksheet.write(1, 1, 'foo', center_thick_rborder)
worksheet.write(2, 1, 'bar', center_thick_rborder)
worksheet.write(3, 1, 'baz', center_thick_rborder)

workbook.close()
```

**Output:**

[image]